# Why Expo StatusBar backgroundColor not working on release apk?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, expo, statusbar

I have an Expo bare workflow project, and I want to color my statusbar to green. On development mode (eas.json ->  "developmentClient": true) expo-statusbar works. However when I create an internal distribution apk build with eas only the "style" property works:
`<Statusbar style="dark" backgroundColor="green">` the color just stays white.

my App.js

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';

  return (
         <View>
           *Rest of the code*
         <StatusBar style="auto" backgroundColor="#519259" />
         </View>
  );
  
}
```

I tried to modify my `color.xml` file in the ./android/app/src/main/res/values/ folder, but it did not help...

color.xml

```
<resources>
  <color name="splashscreen_background">#519259</color>
  <color name="iconBackground">#519259</color>
  <color name="colorPrimary">#519259</color>
  <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#519259</color>
  <color name="notification_icon_color">#519259</color>
</resources>
```

style.xml

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>
    <item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/ResetEditText</item>
    <item name="android:editTextBackground">@drawable/rn_edit_text_material</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
  </style>
  <style name="ResetEditText" parent="@android:style/Widget.EditText">
    <item name="android:padding">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">#c8c8c8</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>
  </style>
  <style name="Theme.App.SplashScreen" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splashscreen</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

[image]